How can I prevent host computer from locking while using Remote Desktop from Hololens?
I am using Remote Desktop to access and control a Windows 10 (Pro license) PC from a Microsoft Hololens 2. I am using Microsoft Connect (WiFi Direct) to connect the 2 devices. However, when I connect them and connect Remote Desktop, it locks the PC which interrupts Connect and they lose connection.
I am limited to apps where I can both mirror and control the PC with Hololens touch controls (so basically limited to RDP) and need a wireless end to end adhoc connection (basically limited to Connect).
Any way to get around my screen locking while still using RDP & connect?

There is no way. RDP was not designed to do this. Use a different program to remote control, such as TeamViewer or AnyDesk.

TeamViewer and AnyDesk when you end their sessions should lock the system.  This is to prevent users with physical access to the machine from continuing the user's session. I suspect the author's problem is different, in that the machine they are using locally is being locked, when they launch the RDP client.  However, I can't be certain, as I don't have access to a Microsoft Hololens 2 and most certainly that would be difficult to provide a screenshot of.

RDP 100% works fine on Hololens when connected over ethernet or Wi-Fi. My issue is the screen locking causing Microsoft Connect (which works fine when not using RDP) to lose connection. TeamViewer and AnyDesk are not compatible with Hololens so that is not an option.

I am just looking for a way to keep my host PC from locking when using RDP

RDP always locks the remote system. For security reasons. There is no way around that. But that isn't the problem. Wifi Direct is the real issue. Get a real access-point. Connect both devices to that using proper Wifi. Or connect them together with a network cable.

@Tonny we are using direct for security reasons. Plan was to do actual adhoc but Windows no longer allows that sothis was the next best thing. Having an access point poses some logistics and security risks and wired is just a pain in the ass

Remote Desktop behaves this way. Remote Control Viewer is Microsoft's tool more analogous to TeamViewer/VNC, that VIEWS a currently logged in and active sessions on the host computer. Remote Desktop projects the desktop session to the viewing computer and locks the session on the host computer because that is what it is designed to do.

@music2myear can't find any microsoft product called remote control viewer... regardless I assume that is not integrated with Hololens so that would not be an option

@ChandlerThornton If you are limited to native tools on the Holo, I stand by what I already said. Get a real network involved so you can use RDP as it is intended to work. AdHoc wifi is bad, I agree, but Wifi Direct isn't really any more secure than regular Wifi (WPA2-PSK) to a (standalone) AP. And a point2point cable is more secure anyway,

@Tonny heard. Looking into this issue I'm coming across people saying that it is a license issue and that a Windows Enterprise license wouldn't cause this issue. Any thoughts??

Remote Control Viewer is a client included in the Configuration Manager/SCCM product. Yea, I doubt it's Hololens compatible. But, Remote Assist might be an option, if you're in a business environment, or have an Azure account.

What you want is not possible, within the limits you have currently defined.
Remote Desktop is not intended to be an "over the shoulder" remove viewing experience, but is instead a projection of the session TO the target computer, with the host interface locked to prevent interruption.
While it is possible to not lock the host computer's screen, which involves multiple sessions, this will not solve your problem: the session you're viewing in the Hololens will still be locked and inaccessible on the host device. See here for more info on that: How do I prevent lock screen of remote computer when remote RDP connection into the computer is started?
You may have better success using Remote Assist, which is an "over the shoulder" remote viewer more akin to Teamviewer/Any Desk/ VNC, and there appears to be support for Remote Assist on Hololens 2. That document appears to specifically require Entra and Dynamics 365 (Microsoft Enterprise Cloud products) for the license and backend for the system. If you're working at home, this may not be viable, but if you're working in a business environment it may be worth exploring.
Microsoft also offer Remote Control Viewer, but I believe this requires the Configuration Manager (SCCM) client software to be installed on the computer you're remotely viewing, and I don't think there's a Hololens client for this tool.
